# Проблема с использованием gettext

Tags: javafx, gettext

Я создавал проект в JavaFx и у меня возникла проблема с gettext. Сама программа должна была стать чем-то вроде простого калькулятора с тремя функциями: сложить, вычесть, умножить, считывая с двух TextField`ов числа и выполняя различные операции, в зависимости от нажатой кнопки. Однако, при запуске программы в поле ответа появляется: "0 + 0 = 0" и т.п. Вот код класса Controller:

```
public class Controller {
@FXML
public TextField txtY;
@FXML
public TextField txtX;
@FXML
public TextArea txtAnswer;
@FXML
public Button btnMult;
@FXML
public Button btnMinus;
@FXML
public Button btnPlus;



private int B;
private int C;
private int A;
private int y1;
private int x1;


public void initialize() {
    String y = txtY.getText();
    String x = txtX.getText();
    try {
        y1 = Integer.parseInt(y);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {

    }
    try {
        x1 = Integer.parseInt(x);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {

    }
    C = x1 * y1;
    A = x1 - y1;
    B = x1 + y1;
}
public void MultyAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    boolean Multy = (C < 0);
    if (Multy){
        try {
            Stage error = new Stage();
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("edit.fxml"));
            error.setTitle("Error");
            error.setMinWidth(100);
            error.setMinHeight(200);
            error.setResizable(false);
            error.setScene(new Scene(root));
            error.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            error.initOwner(((Node) actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());
            error.show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    else{
        txtAnswer.setText(x1 + " * " + y1 + " = " + C);

    }

}
public void MinusAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    boolean Minus = (A < 0);
    if (Minus){
        try {
            Stage error = new Stage();
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("edit.fxml"));
            error.setTitle("Error");
            error.setMinWidth(100);
            error.setMinHeight(200);
            error.setResizable(false);
            error.setScene(new Scene(root));
            error.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            error.initOwner(((Node) actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());
            error.show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    else{
        txtAnswer.setText(x1 + " - " + y1 + " = " + A);

    }


}
public void PlusAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    boolean Plus = (B < 0);
    if (Plus){
        try {
            Stage error = new Stage();
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("edit.fxml"));
            error.setTitle("Error");
            error.setMinWidth(100);
            error.setMinHeight(200);
            error.setResizable(false);
            error.setScene(new Scene(root));
            error.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            error.initOwner(((Node) actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());
            error.show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    else{
        txtAnswer.setText(x1 + " + " + y1 + " = " + B);

    }
}
```

В чем моя ошибка и как ее исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что метод `initialize()` у вас нигде не вызывается, поэтому значения переменных - дефолтные, т.е. для `int` это 0.

Вам надо при совершении операции (сложить, вычесть и умножить) считывать переменные, т.е. вызывать ваш метод `initialize()`

Comment: То есть мне надо поместить initialize() в каждый Аction?

Comment: Получается,что так

Comment: Но метод initialize() нельзя вызывать внутри других методов, разве не так?

Comment: Среда, при вызове initialize(), выдает ошибку expression expected и просит поставить"  ; "

Comment: Ну так поставьте ; после вызова метода

Comment: Однако среда просит поставить ; так:

Comment: public void initialize();

Comment: И далее убрать public, затем void

Comment: Не надо писать паблик войд в том месте,где вы вызываете метод

Comment: т.е просто initialize() и далее?

Comment: initialize(); и все

Comment: Спасибо, запустил программу :)